# WPF force user to stay on TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Am trying to prevent users from leaving a `TabItem` until a condition is met.
I've implemented code on `LostFocus` but it keeps firing continuously. I've tried unsubscribing to the event and then subscribing again after setting the `TabItem` focus. I've also tried setting the `TabItem` `IsSelected` true but still none of these work.

```
private void dataTab_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to proceed?", "No Option chosen", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                NextTab.Focus();
            else {
                dataTab.LostFocus -= dataTab_LostFocus;
                dataTab.IsSelected = true;
                //Also tried dataTab.Focus();
                //e.Handled = true; Also tried.

                dataTab.LostFocus +=dataTab_LostFocus;
            }
}
```

Comment: Can we have a look at implemented code (and xaml)? "keeps firing continuosly" can be solved in multiple ways, but without seeing your attempts it's hard to guess what is wrong.

Comment: See this : https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/how-to-prevent-a-tabitem-from-being-selected/

Comment: Really, so you are calling NextTab.Focus(); and wonder why dataTab_LostFocus is be called?

Comment: You're making a focus call inside a LostFocus handler. Of course that's going to loop endlessly. You shouldn't be doing a Focus call here, unless you dismantle the lost focus handler prior to doing so, but there's probably a bigger design flaw here in terms of what you're doing in your event handlers. If you're having to hook and unhook event handling like this, then it's a sure sign that you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LostFocus` is a wrong event, you have to use `SelectionChanged` of `TabControl` to prevent tab switching.

Below is a working solution (without MVVM logic may looks obscure). Problem is the lack of `SelectionChanging` event (before `SelectedItem` is changed), so you have to remember previously selected item yourself.

xaml:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
    <TabItem x:Name="dataTab" Header="1" /> <!-- the tab with confirmation -->
    <TabItem Header="2" />
    <TabItem Header="3" />
</TabControl>
```

cs:

```
object _previous;
void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var isPreviousWasDataTab = _previous == dataTab;
    _previous = tabControl.SelectedItem; // store SelectedItem for next event
    if (isPreviousWasDataTab && MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        _previous = tabControl.SelectedItem = dataTab;
}
```

Last line may require a bit explanation:

1. `SelectedItem = dataTab` will rise `SelectionChanged` event;
2. `TabControl_SelectionChanged()` will be called;
3. during that call `isPreviousWasDataTab == false`, therefore nothing interesting happens;
4. upon returning we set `_previous = dataTab`.

Comment: Works, thanks. The explanation wasn't necessary but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Wire up an event hanlder to Tabcontrol's Selection changed event.

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
//do your filtering here, and set tab control item to the one you want.
```